# Trying to build kernel on 18.04. No editconfigs option

Tags: kernel, compiling, debian

Trying to build kernel using instructions outlined in:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

After running the lines:

```
fakeroot debian/rules clean
fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs
```

I get this:

[image: No edit configs option]

This ran fine in 17.10 after installing  `ncurses` libraries.

However the editconfigs option appears to have disappeared.

What do I do now apart from twiddle my thumbs?

Comment: To be frank I have switched to writing drivers for Windows using the Wdf with Kmdf on Windows 10. So much better than linux cr*p. Also I get to not have to build kernels anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`apt-get install linux-source`

Also method of kernel compilation has changed

[Use installation guide for 18.04 LTS section 8.6](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/ch08s06.html)

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if in 18.04 you need to run:

```
apt-get source linux-source
```

Instead of:

```
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: Welcome to AU.  Could you explain where you found that?

Comment: I've figured that out trying to build kernel on Ubuntu 18.04. For some reasons "apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)" doesn't download real kernel source, just a stub, which enables downloading pre-built binary images.

Comment: Sorry for the delay however that does not work for 18.04 which seems to be a bit of a disaster as an LTS release.

Comment: You mean "apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)" doesn't work, right? "apt-get source linux-source" is viable workaround. Though would be good to have "canonical way" to work, as all manuals refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

Spent two days compiling the kernel for Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Followed advices from help.ubuntu.com, tried the old way (with fakeroot command) - nothing helped.

And finally I found a working solution:

```
# download kernel sources (deb-src should be uncommented in /etc/apt/sources.list)
apt-get install linux-source kernel-package

# go to folder with kernel sources
#
cd /usr/src/linux-source-x.x.x
# untar
#
tar jxvf linux-source-x.x.x.tar.bz2
# move content to current folder
#
mv linux-source-x.x.x/* .
rm -rf linux-source-x.x.x/
# get nececssary packages
#
apt-get build-dep linux-source
mkdir debian/stamps

# copy old config
#
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
# configure the kernel
#
yes '' | make oldconfig
make menuconfig
make clean
# compile kernel
#
make -j `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-custom
# install kernel modules
#
make modules_install
cd ..
# (!) delete linux-image-x.x.x with dbg prefix (not needed)
#
# install kernel
dpkg -i linux-*.deb
```