# Sublevel version mismatch when trying to compile current kernel

Tags: drivers, kernel, compiling

I am trying to recompile the `sound/usb` module on Ubuntu 18.10 against the running kernel. I get no compilation errors but when I try to load the module I get this error:

```
Invalid module format
```

I am running the `4.18.0-21-lowlatency` kernel.

I obtain the kernel source this way

```
apt source linux
```

This downloads and extracts the source of the `4.18.0` kernel into the `linux-4.18.0` folder.

I copy the `.config` and `Module.symvers` files from `/lib/modules/4.18.0-21-lowlatency/build` to the root of my kernel source directory.

I run `make EXTRAVERSION=-21-lowlatency modules_prepare`, and then `make EXTRAVERSION=-21-lowlatency M=sound/usb`

Running `insmod` results in the following error written into `syslog`

```
snd_usb_audio: version magic '4.18.20-21-lowlatency SMP preempt mod_unload ' should be '4.18.0-21-lowlatency SMP preempt mod_unload '
```

Running `modinfo /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/sound/usb/snd-usb-audio.ko | grep vermagic` returns this

```
vermagic:       4.18.0-21-lowlatency SMP preempt mod_unload
```

Running `modinfo` on my newly compiled module returns this

```
vermagic:       4.18.20-21-lowlatency SMP preempt mod_unload
```

I traced back the issue to the first few lines of the `Makefile`

```
VERSION = 4
PATCHLEVEL = 18
SUBLEVEL = 20
```

If I change the `SUBLEVEL` to `0` and then compile, I can successfully load the module.

So even though I am running the `4.18.0` kernel, and the `apt source linux` seems to download the `4.18.0` kernel, the downloaded files are versioned `4.18.20`.

Is this normal or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. The trouble lies with the method how you obtain the kernel source and how you "build" the kernel. There is a link to what the official way of doing it. I followed it from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile. By the look of it, it appears to be out of date and long reading.

Based on the situation I want to use the official released Ubuntu kernel (not from anywhere else) `apt-get source xxxxx`. It is a folder with Debian folder and a tar ball. Then I follow partial instructions from [Trying to build kernel on 18.04. No editconfigs option](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056598/trying-to-build-kernel-on-18-04-no-editconfigs-option)

1. Download kernel sources (`deb-src` should be uncommented in `/etc/apt/sources.list`)

   ```
   $ apt-get install linux-source kernel-package
   ```
2. Go to folder with kernel sources and untar

   ```
   $ cd /usr/src/linux-source-x.x.x
   $ tar jxvf linux-source-x.x.x.tar.bz2
   ```
3. Move content to current folder

   ```
   $ mv linux-source-x.x.x/* .
   $ rm -rf linux-source-x.x.x/
   ```
4. Get necessary packages

   ```
   $ apt-get build-dep linux-source
   $ mkdir debian/stamps
   ```

Then I can run `fakeroot debian/rules clean` and `fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic binary-perarch`. In the middle I have to manually copy one amd gpu header file to the missing location, otherwise the compilation failed. This way the `fakeroot debian/rules` is using your running kernel configuration (`uname -r`).

If I use the `make menuconfigure` and .config, I end up the same problem as you. So you can use my sample to use official released Ubuntu kernel and `fakeroot debian/rules` to compile. The version of the module could match.

My version is Ubuntu 18.04, and my `uname -r` is 5.3.0-51. I use apt-get to get source around 2020-4-15.

I believe there are other ways to use `make` instead of `fakeroot debian/rules`, and it could help to build in-tree modules.

Comment: I ended up missing a few more things but I figured it out. I wrote a blog post about it here: https://includeguitar.home.blog/2019/06/18/boss-katana-linux-%e2%9d%a4%ef%b8%8f/

Comment: @SzőkeSzabolcs, the method you mentioned involves a manual step to change the kernel version in the downloaded kernel, which might overlook the difference between the original downloaded kernel and the version being changed too. Should this "new" version to have a proper patch instead of a manual version update? Still your step might work to avoid the version check when the binary is deployed. but there will be a risk this binary uses different header or function since the manually changed kernel version is not a real kernel with proper patches. This is an acceptable hack if in emergency.